# Losing internet connection randomly but not streaming to TV

Tags: wireless-networking, router, streaming, tv

I am randomly losing internet connection to my computers and wife's iPad.  But TV continues to stream through Roku device.  all are wireless.  Modem is older Netgear. I can unplug and restart and everything is fine until the next time. Why then is tv continuing to receive internet but none of the computers?

Comment: Modem is older Netgear.  ... This gear ages just like computers.   Consider replacing it.

Comment: Are you on the same room? Whats the wifi signal level on all 3?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: WiFi signal is good. Computers are in multiple rooms.  Wi Fi seems to stay connected but lose internet.  Most puzzling is why TV streaming continues even after internet loss to computers.  I do want a new router but that is another issue.

Comment: The TV can be playing cached content, i.e., content already downloaded and kept in memory until needed. This typically compensates for intermittent connections.